# Optionals in designing Swift API

Tags: swift, option-type, api-design

I'm creating a new API to use in my app. The Swift API guidelines have no mention of optionals.

I have structured my API to accept data in one format and return it in another format for use in the creation. i.e.

```
func createMyDataFromYourData(data: YourData?) -> MyData? {}
```

The function checks to see if data is nil, and proceeds appropriately. After writing this it occurred to me that the API should only deal with non-optionals and the user should be checking for nil before passing. Have we decided on a rule yet?

Comment: You should use Optionals only if they are _meaningful_. You have not revealed what your function does, but that is where the whole point lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a "rule" for this.  It's dependent on how your app will work.  In your case, you're trying to create a MyData object, so I would suggest you instead do:

```swift
class MyData {
    convenience init?(data: YourData?) {
        guard let data = data else { return nil }

        self.init()

        // Do whatever with data
    }
}
```

That way it's very obvious you're creating a new object when you call it like so:

```
let obj = MyData(data: yourDataObject)
```

obj is a nullable object itself.  It's also possible you still create a MyData object if YourData is nil, and so in that case you'd just not make it nullable.

Comment: Thanks! Yet another "duh" moment. I'm doing a conversion from my data model to HealthKit so I'll be throwing convenience inits into class extensions.

Answer (score 0):

There *really* can't be any *general* rules regarding this. It depends on your use case. I'd say a good rule of thumb is to design your API for your current needs, otherwise you risk over-engineering things that really aren't that complex.

As a (somewhat contrived) example you could for instance have the following two requirements:

1. A function that returns an array of prime-numbers from an array of Ints:

   ```
   func primeNumberFromIntegers(integers: [Int]) -> [Int] {
       // implementation goes here
   }
   ```

If you *know* that you'll *always* want to iterate through whatever numbers that are returned there's no point having an optional return-value, but rather have the function return an empty array.

2. You might require a function to return the *highest* available prime-number from an array of Ints this would probably make more sense:

   ```
   func highestPrimeNumberFromIntegers(integers: [Int]) -> Int? {
       //Implementation
   }
   ```

Why optional? Because the array of Ints you send in *may* or may *not* include any prime-numbers. The only *sensible* return value if no prime-number exist is nil.